# automatically assigned argument to Python Default Arguments

Tags: python

Default Argument is not working in my case.

if I specify the argument, then it works. but otherwise, It's different from what I expected before.

```
def splitInteger(a, rtn = []):
    rtn.insert(0, a % 10)
    if(a >= 10):
        return splitInteger(int(a/10), rtn)
    else:
        return rtn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(3, 20):
        rtn = splitInteger(i)
        print(rtn)
```

What I expected was

```
[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[1, 7]
[1, 8]
[1, 9]
```

But the output is

```
[3]
[4, 3]
[5, 4, 3]
[6, 5, 4, 3]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 6, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 8, 1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
[1, 9, 1, 8, 1, 7, 1, 6, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

As you can see above, I didn't pass any argument to the second parameter, so I thought like It will receive empty array automatically.

Can you tell me why this thing happens?

Comment: This is a very common issue, see [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `splitInteger` is modifying `rtn` everytime it is called.

```
# First iteration
splitInteger(1)
# [1]
# but now, rtn = [1] 
# Second iteration
splitInteger(1)
# [1, 1]
```

Making a new list *inside* a function will solve your problem

```
def splitInteger(a, rtn = []):
    r = rtn.copy() 
    r.insert(0, a % 10)
    if(a >= 10):
        return splitInteger(int(a/10), r)
    else:
        return r
```

Results:

```
for i in range(3, 20):
    rt = splitInteger(i)
    print(rt)

[3]
[4]
[5]
[6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
[1, 0]
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1, 4]
[1, 5]
[1, 6]
[1, 7]
[1, 8]
[1, 9]
```

Comment: Good suggestion ! Thank you so much.